# The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

I am getting invalid aws access key id error . The code is below

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, // your AWS access id
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, // your AWS access key
});

// actual function for uploading file
async function uploadFile(file) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, // bucket you want to upload to
    Key: `fileupload/scanskill-${Date.now()}-${file.name}`, // put all image to fileupload folder with name scanskill-${Date.now()}${file.name}`
    Body: file.data,
    ACL: "public-read",
  };
  const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
  return data.Location; // returns the url location
}
```

The problem is not with the code because i tried nearly half a dozen different tutorials and always the same error . I have the updated credentials in the .env file also on the /.aws/credentials file . However i keep getting the same error . i have looked for solutions online which say create another IAM but i cannot do so as i am using a AWS educate account for my uni project . any solutions will be appreciated.

for it to work but the same error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and secrets, please export them as environment variables where the code runs.

If you want to use ~/.aws/credentials, skip mentioning them in client creation

just use what is needed like region

```
const client = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
```

Comment: have updated and am getting 
TypeError: S3Client is not a constructor error .

Comment: sorry, updated the answer

Comment: thanks . removing the const s3 .... and replacing it with const client = new AWS.S3(); works perfectly . appreciate it ! @omuthu